# tools:listheader doesn't work although tools:listitem does

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a fragment layout that contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/blankList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listheader="@layout/menu_header"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />
</FrameLayout>
```

My fragment_item contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#f0f0f0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_article_text_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My menu_header contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that for some reason when I run it the app the fragment works, the list appears and the items of it are fine, but the header simply isn't there.

any help anyone?

*** IMPORTANT FACT ***
on the preview, it does work but it doesn't when I run it

Answer (score 4):

> My problem is that for some reason when I run it the app the fragment
>   works, the list appears and the items of it are fine, but the header
>   simply isn't there.
>
> - IMPORTANT FACT * on the preview, it does work but it doesn't when I run it

=> Looks like you have misunderstood about tools attribute. Those are design time attributes, means that it's helpful while designing layouts. Yes those are not meant for runtime and so obviously it won't be appeared in app.

To clarify it by giving you an example, `android:text="Hello World` and `tools:text="Hello World"`. You should put demo/testing data in layout using tools attribute so user will not be seeing those data but it will be helpful to developers to see that there are views available in layout. In fact, they can adjust margins, paddings and all other layout design time operations!

Comment: First of all thanks a lot but your answer forces me to ask another, How do I actually add a header to a list? @Paresh Mayani

Comment: @ItayBraha you mean section header, right? If yes then you need to define 2 view holder, one is section title header and another is item view holder. Check more on Google, lot of resources are available already